# Bluetooth run receive fails

Tags: android

I am using the code sample found here http://goldenhillbooks.com/blog/?p=59#respond. I modified the Run with the below code.  The issue I have is when I disconnect one of the connected Bluetooth devices the app crashes.  If I comment the run section it does not crash.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

```
public void run() {
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (threadNumber>0) {
        try {
            int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();   

            if(bytesAvailable > 0) {
              final byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
              inStream.read(packetBytes);
              //myLabel.setText(packetBytes.toString());
              for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++) {
                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                if(b == delimiter) {
                  byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                  System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                  final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                  readBufferPosition = 0;
                  Log.d(TAG,
                        "BtConnectionThread run while loop: received from arduino:" + data);

                        Intent e = new  Intent("com.Ryan.myhue.BT_LISTENER");
                        e.putExtra("notification_event",data);
                        mycontext.sendBroadcast(e);

                }
                else {
                  readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                }
              }
            } //bytesAvailable  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, 
                    "BtConnectionThread run while loop: problem reading");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting a flag in the disconnect to exit the run if disconnected.

```
 while (this.running == true) {
```